# Are these two grammars similar?

Tags: automata, formal-grammar, finite-automata

Language is

```
L = {a^nb^m | n.m >=1}
```

Grammar 1 :

```
 S->AB
 B -> bB|b
 A-> aA|a
```

Grammar 2 :

```
S->aSB|epsilon
B -> b|epsilon
```

Comment: Can the first grammar generate epsilon? Can the second?

Comment: thanks ... i just completely overlooked epsilon ! @mrp . You can put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second grammar can generate epsilon whereas the first one can not, so they are not equivalent. Since epsilon is not in $L$, only the first grammar generates $L$.